# Given a set of relationships, what is the most efficient algorithm to calculate the ordered set

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
   c > b
   d > b
   a > d
   c > a
```

Given such transitive relationships, what is the most efficient algorithm to calculate the relation between all of them?

Comment: Note: It's an awful idea to downvote answers to your questions, because very soon people will stop helping you.

Comment: He downvoted both of ours lol.

Comment: You cant define sort without transitivity. How would you sort something like a > b, b > c, c > a?

Answer (score 1):

Build a graph, and use [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to retrieve the nodes in sorted order.

If you use am adjacency list representation and a hash map for the vertices of your graph, the overall timing will be O(N), where `N` is the number of relationships that you have. Building the graph is linear in the number of relationships that you have. The topological sort is O(|V|+|E|), where |V| is the number of vertices, and |E| is the number of edges. The number of edges is equal to the number of relationships, i.e. `N`, and `V` has the upper bound of `2*N`, so it we have O(3*N), which is O(N).

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually describing in your case is a topological sort problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Where instead of a graph, you have orderings of letters. Each letter represents a node and each comparison operator represents a directed edge. The standard algorithm for computing the topological sort of a pairwise orderings is as follows:

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted elements
S ← Set of all nodes with no incoming edges
while S is non-empty do
    remove a node n from S
    add n to tail of L
    for each node m with an edge e from n to m do
        remove edge e from the graph
        if m has no other incoming edges then
            insert m into S
if graph has edges then
    return error (graph has at least one cycle)
else 
    return L (a topologically sorted order)
```

Keep in mind that for you to find an ordering, there can be no cycles. i.e.:

```
a < b //This
b < c //contains
c < a //a cycle!
```

This is called a DAG. Directed acyclic graph. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Here is an example of how to do it in Python: [Topological sort python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038876/topological-sort-python)