# How to install multiple .whl files in the right order

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, python-wheel

I have recently found myself in the situation of having to install all dependencies (20+) of a python project on a machine without internet connection. I used `pip download ...` to get all the `*.whl` files and transferred them manually. Only now I fully appreciate the genius of pip and how it figures out the dependency tree on its own and manages to install every package in the right order. E.g. a package depends on the `requests` package which on its own depends on the `urllib3` package and so on.

I wanted an automated way to install all these dependencies on the machine using the command console or python itself, so I turned to StackOverflow and found these solutions:
[How to install multiple whl files in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314517/how-to-install-multiple-whl-files-in-cmd)

Nearly all suggested solutions work for me, however have the disadvantage of having to run them multiple times until no installation fails anymore! This is due to the scripts/commands sorting the packages alphabetically and trying to install them in that order (e.g. trying to install `requests` before `urllib3` is in place).

Is there a smarter way to do this with only executing a script/command on time?

Comment: As a frame challenge - have you looked at "hosting" your own PyPI repository on the machine without an internet connection?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127695/1149933

Comment: No, until this moment I did not know that was possible. Do you have recommendations/links for material explaining the process?

Comment: I updated my comment with a link to an answer to just that question (I think) while you were typing that response.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Why does the order matter? It definitely should not matter. If it does matter, then something might be broken somewhere... Installing _wheels_ is only a matter of unzipping the wheels files into the right folders (a bit more complicated, but not that much). Have you tried adding a `--no-deps` in your installation command? Maybe something like `python -m pip install --no-deps wheels/*.whl`?

Comment: This is it! Since I'm sure that I have all dependencies in form of .whl files it is justifiable to use the `--no-deps` flag. Although Adam's suggestion works as well this is of course simpler. If you want to make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This directory full of wheel distribution files that you created is sometimes called a *wheelhouse*. They are often used to make repeatable and/or offline installations.

A common way to install from a wheelhouse is:

```
python -m pip install --no-index --no-deps path/to/wheelhouse/*.whl
```

If all the wheels for all dependencies and their dependencies are in the wheelhouse, then the installation order does not matter and there is no need to connect to any remote package index (for dependency resolution, etc.). That is why we can use the `--no-deps` and `--no-index` flags.

***Reference***:

- ["*Using a wheelhouse (AKA Installation Bundles)*" section of *pip*'s documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/repeatable-installs/#using-a-wheelhouse-aka-installation-bundles)

---

***Aside***:

> Only now I fully appreciate the genius of pip and how it figures out the dependency tree on its own and manages to install every package in the right order.

*pip*'s dependency resolver is [*`resolvelib`*](https://pypi.org/project/resolvelib/). There is a simple [example on its source code repository](https://github.com/sarugaku/resolvelib/blob/e91ef74ad0aec4795e2ffc1ef1686004c3dbd6be/examples/pypi_wheel_provider.py) showing how to use it to solve for wheels on *PyPI*.

Comment: `ERROR: *.whl is not a valid wheel filename.`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way of figuring the correct installation order is to sort packages according to their dependencies. *Those topics were already discussed separately in couple other SO questions, so I will link to them instead of repeating.* The "Safe installation algorithm" looks as follows:

1. **Read metadata of all packages.**
   [this question explains how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170588/list-dependencies-of-python-wheel-file) Focus on package name and dependencies.
2. **Sort them topologically** [Article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and [another helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038876/topological-sort-python)
3. Install packages according to the order.

Comment: Although this is a very systematic way of tackling the problem I feel like this answer is missing the point of the question. The aim was to find a way of automating the process in one script or command. Before trying to find out the dependency graph manually and digging through the metadata of the packages I can also simply execute my script n times where n in the worst case is the depth of the graph until no installation fails anymore.

Comment: For info: _pip_'s dependency resolver is [_resolvelib_](https://pypi.org/project/resolvelib/). There is also a [simple example](https://github.com/sarugaku/resolvelib/blob/e91ef74ad0aec4795e2ffc1ef1686004c3dbd6be/examples/pypi_wheel_provider.py)  showing how to use it to solve for _wheels_ on _PyPI_.