# ERROR: *.whl is not a valid wheel filename

Tags: shell, cmd, pip

`*` or asterisk command is not being recognized in shell and command prompt when below command is executed.

I have multiple python wheels in wheelhouse directory.

```
python -m pip install --no-index --no-deps C:\Users\Admin\test2\wheelhouse\*.whl

WARNING: Requirement 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\test2\\wheelhouse\\*.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

ERROR: *.whl is not a valid wheel filename.
```

[How to install multiple .whl files in the right order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844775/how-to-install-multiple-whl-files-in-the-right-order)

Comment: (I do not think it even works to contact someone this way, I did not receive any notification, but by chance I read this question anyway) -- It seems like it could be a limitation of the Windows command prompt, that it can not handle the `*`-wildcard in this case. But I do not have a Windows available right now to test this. I am quite sure it would work on Linux (bash-like shell).

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10808

Comment: Thank you! found a workaround for that issue :                                                           
FOR %i in (wheelhouse\*.whl) DO python -m pip install %i

Answer (score 0):

```
 FOR %i in (wheelhouse\*.whl) DO python -m pip install --no-index --no-deps %i
```

This command works in windows PowerShell.